# WebDAV share: how to mount on CLI with access to non-priviledgs user and no /etc/fstab?

Tags: command-line-interface, webdav

I have never used WebDAV before (I like sshf) but I am trying it.  I want to mount a remote WebDAV share that I set up on my server, on my local computer.

If I try as non-priv `user` I can't access mount command fully.

If I try as `root` I can't access the folder as `user`.  I used this command:

`sudo mount -t davfs -o noexec https://nextcloud.example.com/remote.php/webdav/ /mnt/dav/`

I don't want to use /etc/fstab because I don't want the share to be mounted before I establish a VPN (but I do want `mount -a` in `rc.local`)

Is there something like `-o idmap=user` I can use for WebDAV?

Using Linux obviously.

Comment: I can't off-hand tell you why you can't issue the mount command is non-root user but: [`man mount.davfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.davfs) shows a mount option **`uid=user`**
*The owner of the mounted file system. It may be a numeric ID or a user name. Only when mounted by root, this may be different from the mounting user.*

Comment: @HBruijin I read that but obviously too quickly.  I literally typed `uid=user` because I was used to `-o idmap=user`.  I will try this again when I can come back to this issue.